# How to set Persian charset in shapefile generated from GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, web-gis, iran

I have a .NET based web-gis application, and in that application different users update layers (layers information are stored in SQL server).

When I generate shapefile from that layer in GeoServer from WFS Service and then open it in ArcMap, ArcMap does not display the Persian values at all; instead it displays "????????".

In geoserver store i have used "windows1256".

I have tried different charset but I did not get the correct shapefile.

Comment: Could you have a look into the .cst or .cpg file that Geoserver also puts into the zip file? Which encoding is set there?

Comment: yeah, it is utf-8

Comment: And have you checked which encoding is set in your database? By default this should also be utf-8

Comment: the collation is latin..........do u think that causes me problems?

Comment: could you use another format? Shapefiles and charsets is always a bit difficult.

Comment: could you try to publish a utf8 encoded layer in Geoserver?
as long as the encoding of your database is utf8 this should work.

Comment: i did that too,it did not work out